# Angular 17 - Exception on getEnvironmentInjectorProviders

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need help on this exception (image attached) that I can't solve.

I have two standalone components (images below), when I open dialog from parent I got an exception on (Could not determine where injector providers were configured.
at throwError (core.mjs:392:11) )

LoginComponent ==> is parent
ForgotPasswordComponent ==> is child

Thank you in advance for your help.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iHOy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vhb9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmbyo.png)

I wanna just open the ForgotPasswordComponent from LoginComponent in MatDialog.

Comment: My use case implementation work like I execpted, but in my consol, I have this exception that I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you try to add `importProvidersFrom([MatDialogModule]),` in your application providers  ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler no, I'll try and let you know, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to to Angular 17.0.3 version fixes this issue.

[This](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52932) is the GitHub issue about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using standalone components, the error happens when I navigate to a route with providers configured, even if that is an empty array(`route` is a helper function to setup `Route`):

[image]

The injector is then being checked for having "root" scope, this fails as it is an EnvironmentalInjector, and leads to an error)

[image]